# Modify duplicating random number generator to non-duplicating random number generator

Tags: java, random

```
int size = 5;

int[] list = new int[size];

Random rand = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   list[i] = rand.nextInt(100);            
}

for(int element : list)
   System.out.print(element + " ");
```

I'm trying to modify this random number generator so that it will not duplicate random generated numbers. How can I accomplish this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to be sure that random numbers are unique and not duplicated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557049/how-to-be-sure-that-random-numbers-are-unique-and-not-duplicated)

Comment: If you think you want random numbers without duplicates, then you don't understand your problem. Usually what people really want is a specific set of numbers (or items in a list) *in random order*, which is an entirely different thing. Google "shuffling". Or perhaps you want a random sample of a set, using a partial shuffle or something like Floyd's algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do it. A simple variant on what you already have:

```
int size = 5;
int[] values = new int[100];
int[] list = new int[size];
for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) values[i] = i;
Random rand = new Random();
int ctListSize = 0;
int xList = 0;
while( true ){
    int iCandidateValue = rand.nextInt(100);
    if( values[ iCandidateValue ] == 0 ) continue; // already used
    list[ xList++ ] = iCandidateValue;
    values[ iCandidateValue ] = 0;
    if( xList == size || xList == 100 ) break;
}

for(int element : list) System.out.print(element + " ");
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, your code worked Perfect! I really appreciate all your help! Thanks a million! :-) :-) :-) :-) Smiling all the way to the bank!

Comment: This will of course work as well for small ranges. Another way of doing this is shuffling the array and taking the first 5 values (which should be deterministic and have consistent runtime).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks Maarten, I appreciate the info.

Comment: @TylerDurden Tyler, if you would please, give me a line-by-line explanation of the non-duplicating random number generator code you provided me; I'd really appreciate it. This will help me tremendously in my Java learning curve. Thanks a million! :-) :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 2):

The dumbest way imaginable is actually an acceptable strategy: just discard any generated number which is already present in the array. However you want to improve on this, you'll be facing either space or time costs (or both). For the array size you show in the question, there is no need for that.

Comment: Yep, this works well while size is small and the range is big.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Hi Maarten, yes, very true; you and Marko Topolnik are correct; when the size is small and the range is big, the chance of duplicates is significantly reduced, but the final project will display 50 random generated numbers and I wanted a way to use a range of no more than 50, and Tyler Durden made that possible. HOORAY! :-) :-) :-)

Comment: With a range of "no more than 50" and 50 distinct numbers to pick from it, your problem is called "shuffling a list" and is supported by the JDK with a single API call.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the generates values in a `Set` (which is a data structure that holds **unique** elements).

Each time you generate a new number, you can check if it already exists in the `Set`. For example:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

Random rand = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < size; )
{
   int next = rand.nextInt(100);;
   if (!set.contains(next)) {
       set.add(next);
       i++;
   } 
}
```

Note that I'm increasing the index **only** when a number that hasn't been generated yet is generated.

Comment: Hi kocko, I had trouble with Set and HashSet, compile error: "cannot find symbol." I've never used Set and HashSet, so I wouldn't know right off the top of my head how to avoid the compile error; I'm still in the Java learning curve, less than a year under my belt. Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: Use an IDE that can find the imports you need. `Set` and `HashSet` are part of the collections framework in `java.util`. You need to know about these classes to write modern Java.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks Maarten, I appreciate the info.

Answer (score 0):

Have a list which contains all the numbers you have seen with the RNG. Then check the list if it's present - if it is, don't add it to the list. If it isn't add to the list.

```
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

      int num = rand.nextInt(100);
      if (list.contains(num){
          break;
      }else{
         list.add(num);
      }
```

This way you can return the list and see no duplicates.

Or think about using a Set data structure which only allows unique keys.